# Is it possible force UI autorotation in iOS?

Tags: ios, uikit, device-orientation

I have an auto-rotating view which should be only horizontal at some specific time. I tried changing return value of -shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: for specific time, but it didn't work as I expected. Because there is no way to force currently vertical oriented UI to horizontal. Is this possible...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a conclusion there is no such thing. I decided to implement rotation manually, myself instead of autorotation. I didn't believed this is possible, but I realized I can do exact things with `UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification`.

There is `-[UIApplication statusBarOrientation]` property which looks forces rotation of UI in simulator, but it's just rotating status bar only. However, that's important and preferred for basis for UI orientation by the simulator.

I used it and now rotate everything manually. this is more easier to make and manage.